# How to check a specific format of string in C

Tags: c

I have the following code that accepts a string that resembles hours.. I want to check if the string format is actually `xx-yy` where `xx` resembles an hour as does `yy`.. The code worked fine but when I input `"02-13-"` it returns true but I want it to return false cause it's not correct (cause it has `-` at the end)

```
bool hourIsValid(char * hours) {
  int openH = 0;
  int closeH = 0;

  if ((sscanf(hours, "%d-%d", & openH, & closeH) == 2) && openH >= 0 && openH <= 24 && closeH >= 0 && closeH <= 24) {
    if (openH >= closeH) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: sscanf is really not the sharpest tool for writing parsers

Comment: at this pause point i don't want to actually change it cause it works fine

Comment: i am thinking maybe add an array and initiate it to zero and check if the array in the 3 place not null return false

Comment: Sure about C++, or do you actually mean C?

Comment: You have to decide what it is you want to do. Do you want to read in a line and see if that line complies with your format? There has to be some rule for when you stop reading input and switch to parsing that input to see if it's valid -- when do you want that to happen?

Comment: no c sorry for the mistake i am gonna fix it

Comment: i want to read the string hours and check if it is in the write format thats it

Comment: try such as `"%d-%d%c"` or `"%d-%d%n"`

Comment: ok i am gonna try it now

Comment: it is still  working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on how "pedantic" your code has to be when deciding if an input is valid or not. For example, you might expect `"2-14"`, `"02 - 15"`, `"  2-14   "` as valid, or you might not. It depends.

If you want to get a pedantic version that accepts only the exact format `"dd-dd"` with no leading or trailing characters or white spaces and with exactly a two-digit format for each hour value, you could check the string as follows before reading in the values with your `sscanf`-code:

```
if (strlen(hours) != 5)
    return 0;

if (hours[2] != '-')
    return 0;

if ( !isdigit(hours[0])
    || !isdigit(hours[1])
    || !isdigit(hours[3])
    || !isdigit(hours[4])
    )
    return 0;
```

Comment: i have a question

Comment: what if the number of hour was for example 1:23 and not 01:23 what can i do in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool hourIsValid(
      char *I__hours
      )
   {
   long openH, closeH;

   openH=strtol(I__hours, &I__hours, 10);
   if(      '-' != *I__hours                   // Ensure that there is a dash between the two numbers in the string.
         || 0 >= openH                         // Ensure that the 1st number in the string is non-negative.
         || 24 <= openH                        // Ensure that the 1st number in the string is 24 or less.
         )
      return(false);

   ++I__hours;                                 // Skip over the dash between the two numbers.
   closeH=strtol(I__hours, &I__hours, 10);
   if(      *I__hours                          // Ensure that there are no additional characters beyond the 2nd number.
         || 0 >= closeH                        // Ensure that the 2nd number in the string is non-negative.
         || 24 <= closeH                       // Ensure that the 2nd number in the string is 24 or less.
         || openH >= closeH                    // Ensure that the 1st number is less or equal to the 2nd number.
         )
      return(false);

   return(true);
   }
```

Comment: Why not use `<stdbool.h>` and `bool`, `true`, `false`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good idea.

Comment: what if the number of hour was for example 1:23 and not 01:23 what can i do in this case ?

Comment: @newprogrammerha,  the input posed by the question required a dash (-) to separate two "hour" values.  Hence, for both 1:23, and 01:23, the function will return false.  However, both 1-23 and 01-23 would be correctly parsed, and true would be returned.